# print complex dictionary content recursively to tree

Tags: python, lxml

given the following xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<xmi:XMI xmlns:uml="http://www.omg.org/spec/UML/20110701" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20110701" xmlns:thecustomprofile="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/thecustomprofile/1.0">
    <xmi:Documentation exporter="Enterprise Architect" exporterVersion="6.5"/>
    <uml:Model xmi:type="uml:Model" name="EA_Model">
        <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="EAPK_FE6A1ABF_4C30_4d66_A200_B29CA55BB50F" name="Root 2">
            <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="EAPK_B25F74E8_35C4_4404_B8C6_C733378D8AFA" name="Package1"/>
            <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="EAPK_8302563D_1E79_40a0_9D73_4E7959BDE221" name="Package2">
                <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="EAPK_1D028092_F199_4043_B690_6373C191272C" name="Package2.1"/>
                <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Package" xmi:id="EAPK_497888C3_5A47_4d13_BC81_DEF83A199E45" name="Package2.2">
                    <ownedComment xmi:type="uml:Comment" xmi:id="EAID_3A953EDE_D11A_4900_B583_36D8C904E4A1" body="Note"/>
                    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="EAID_887464C9_87B5_441c_9882_6C9E9A0CA720" name="Class1">
                        <generalization xmi:type="uml:Generalization" xmi:id="EAID_EAE102FD_9B8C_4f91_B7C5_7A87EBBE6F7B" general="EAID_7A45F41C_DFDF_4ef9_BFDA_9D7405BCB6A3"/>
                    </packagedElement>
                    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Association" xmi:id="EAID_5513510F_B792_4008_877F_7109B223CE5C">
                        <memberEnd xmi:idref="EAID_dst13510F_B792_4008_877F_7109B223CE5C"/>
                        <memberEnd xmi:idref="EAID_src13510F_B792_4008_877F_7109B223CE5C"/>
                        <ownedEnd xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="EAID_src13510F_B792_4008_877F_7109B223CE5C" association="EAID_5513510F_B792_4008_877F_7109B223CE5C" aggregation="shared">
                            <type xmi:idref="EAID_78E607A2_9161_4e62_887F_9585CF6771DA"/>
                        </ownedEnd>
                    </packagedElement>
                    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="EAID_78E607A2_9161_4e62_887F_9585CF6771DA" name="Class2">
                        <ownedAttribute xmi:type="uml:Property" xmi:id="EAID_dst13510F_B792_4008_877F_7109B223CE5C" association="EAID_5513510F_B792_4008_877F_7109B223CE5C">
                            <type xmi:idref="EAID_887464C9_87B5_441c_9882_6C9E9A0CA720"/>
                        </ownedAttribute>
                    </packagedElement>
                    <packagedElement xmi:type="uml:Class" xmi:id="EAID_7A45F41C_DFDF_4ef9_BFDA_9D7405BCB6A3" name="Class3"/>
                    <ownedRule xmi:type="uml:Constraint" xmi:id="EAID_7E61CF9B_4137_4ee8_878D_61F03566DAE8">
                        <specification xmi:type="uml:OpaqueExpression" xmi:id="EAID_OE000000_4137_4ee8_878D_61F03566DAE8" body="pvf_Class2"/>
                    </ownedRule>
                </packagedElement>
            </packagedElement>
        </packagedElement>
        <profileApplication xmi:type="uml:ProfileApplication" xmi:id="profileap_thecustomprofile">
            <appliedProfile xmi:type="uml:Profile" href="http://www.sparxsystems.com/profiles/thecustomprofile/1.0#thecustomprofile"/>
        </profileApplication>
    </uml:Model>
</xmi:XMI>
```

which i read into a xml file using the xmltodict lib:

```
with open(xml_file, "r") as f:
    xml_content = f.read()
dct = xmltodict.parse(xml_content)
```

I am struggling with the nested loop to print the tree. I am not sure how to reset the counter for example to start a new node. I am also not sure if i am on the right way. I don`t want to use any XPATH stuff here, just keep the loop as general as possible..

```
def p(d, counter = 0, c = 0):
    for k, v in d.items():
        print("|___"*counter, k)
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            c = len(v)
            if(c > counter):
                counter += 1
            else:
                counter = 0
            p(v, counter, c)
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for i, v2 in enumerate(v):
                print("|___" * counter, k)
                p(v2, counter)
```

The result should be like:

```
xmi
|_Model
   |_packagedElement (Root 2)
       | _ packagedElement (Package1)
       | - packagedElement (Package2)
             | _ packagedElement (Package2.1)
             | _ packagedElement (Package2.2)
                   | _ ownedComment (Note)
                   | _ ...
```

Any help is really appreciated..

Comment: How do you feel about [pp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.pp) pretty printing? `from pprint import pp; pp(some_dict, sort_dicts=True, width=1)`. I mean, do you need to code it yourself, so using library code would be cheating? See also the json module [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html): `json.dumps(some_dict, sort_keys=True, indent=4)`

Comment: Yes, i need to export it basically with parent child relations to a database as in the tree... i just thought asking the question that way will help understand it better..

Comment: Good. If you now know how to solve it to your satisfaction, then please [post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) a solution.